# How does the MVC framework validate a code first POCO with DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, code-first

In my unit tests, I would like to force the validation of a code first POCO that has DataAnnotations on it.

The MVC framework must be doing it behind the scenes, and basically I would like to know how, so I can hopefully make use of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The MVC framework bust be doing it behind the scenes, and basically I
>   would like to know how, so I can hopefully make use of it.

It's the default model binder that is responsible for invoking the validation of the model once it has bound it from the request values.

You could invoke the validation process manually by using a `ValidationContext`.

Let's suppose that you have a model:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "the Bar is absolutely required")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and then you could unit test it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void The_Bar_Is_Required()
{
    // arrange
    var foo = new Foo();
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var context = new ValidationContext(foo, null, null);

    // act
    var actual = Validator.TryValidateObject(foo, context, results);

    // assert
    Assert.IsFalse(actual);
}
```

Alternatively to using DataAnnotations you could use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) to perform validation on your view models. It [integrates nicely with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and it allows you to [unit test your validators](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation) in a very elegant way.

Comment: Thanks, that is a big help, one more thing I need though, is to then reflect the result of this validation on the controller, so that the ModelState is set accordingly, any ideas?

Comment: Wait a minute. A unit test means that something is tested in isolation. You shouldn't have the same test for your controller action and for validation. You should have one unit test for validation (already shown in my answer) and another unit test for your controller action. In the unit test for your controller action if you want to simulate ModelState.IsValid returning false then simply manually add an error to the ModelState inside your unit test: `ModelState.AddModelError("Foo", "The foo field is required");`. Now when you invoke the controller action the ModelState won't be valid.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have at the moment and it works.  I just thought it would be nicer if I could unit test the action with a model that would fail validation, so I could check that a genuine model validation failure would be picked up and handled correctly by the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I just [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110286/how-to-unit-test-the-dataannotationsmodelbinder-in-asp-net-mvc-2/17231644#17231644).

I usually unit test my model validation setup by directly calling the facade methods of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.

I wrote a article on the subject http://timoch.com/blog/2013/06/unit-testing-model-validation-with-mvcs-dataannotations/

I end up with code like this (the article show a cleaner and reusable unit test base class for model validation)

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource("ValidationRule_Source")]
public void ValidationRule(ValidateRuleSpec spec) {
    // Arrange
    var model = CreateValidPersonModel();
    // Apply bad valud
    model.GetType().GetProperty(spec.MemberName).SetValue(model, spec.BadValue);

    // Act
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var success = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model), validationResults, true);

    // Assert
    Expect(success, False);
    Expect(validationResults.Count, EqualTo(1));
    Expect(validationResults.SingleOrDefault(r => r.MemberNames.Contains(spec.MemberName)), Not.Null);
}

public IEnumerable<ValidateRuleSpec> ValidationRule_Source() {
    yield return new ValidateRuleSpec() {
        BadValue = null,
        MemberName = "FirstName"
    };
    yield return new ValidateRuleSpec() {
        BadValue = string.Empty,
        MemberName = "FirstName"
    };
    yield return new ValidateRuleSpec() {
        BadValue = null,
        MemberName = "LastName"
    };
    /* ... */
}
```

I don't like trusting code to just work so I systematically write unit test for my model validation code. However, I do trust the framework/model binder to execute validation. 
This unit test allows me to write controller that trust the validation is OK.